# Sitecore 9 - Cloning instances

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-framework, sim

In all previous versions of `Sitecore 9`, we could easily clone and export instances using SIM.

Hence was wondering if there is such an option to do so for version 9 `Initial Release` or `Update 1`. Thanks.

Comment: You were using SIM or SIF?

Comment: @chorpo SIF. Tried using SIM export and it doesnt work with Sitecore 9

Comment: then I think you need to correct your question as you have SIM there :)

Comment: @chorpo added the SIM tag. Didnt know it existed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are no features built in to SIF to support this (as of 1.2.0) but it may be possible to do so in the future as more features are added (e.g. direct SQL support for db backups).

Answer (score 0):

You can take backup of the Sitecore 9 sites using SIM now. I am sure you might have encountered a bug like this.

[image]

I read on the SIM site that they fix the issues on QA version so frequently And make sure you have the latest SIM QA version. Please download SIM QA version: http://dl.sitecore.net/updater/qa/sim/

That will be solved.

Comment: Hey, just tried your suggestion. Seem to be getting errors still. 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at SIM.Tool.Base.Profiles.ProfileManager.get_IsValid()

Comment: Allow write permissions to the inetpub folder.

Comment: the SIM writes on the root folder on the inetpub. so it needs permissions. check this image, https://www.screencast.com/t/RtCRDmad28 It worked. Also, this problem might exist if your PC user is on Domain user. The domain user admin does not have complete privileges to allow write permissions.

Comment: ok, managed to export at last. Apparently was wrong credentials to do with my connectionstrings which was preventing it. However, can you successfully 'Import Solution' at destination server too? Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried this one. Let's see this one too

Comment: I was able to take the backup but not able to import. It says "wrong package for import the package does not contain Website/Web.config file"